# How to upload a certificate to Application gateway through Azure ARM Template

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I am trying to upload a certificate to app gateway through my ARM template script. How to do this via the ARM script. Below is my script:

```
"backendHttpSettingsCollection": [
                    {
                        "name": "appGatewayBackendHttpSettings",
                        "properties": {
                            "Port": 80,
                            "Protocol": "Http",
                            "CookieBasedAffinity": "Disabled"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "httpssettings",
                        "etag": "W/\"f5659c7c-d83a-431b-b456-097622a27c7b\"",
                        "properties": {
                            "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
                            "port": 8443,
                            "protocol": "Https",
                            "cookieBasedAffinity": "Enabled",
                            "connectionDraining": {
                                "enabled": false,
                                "drainTimeoutInSec": 60
                            },
                            "pickHostNameFromBackendAddress": false,
                            "path": null,
                            "requestTimeout": 300,
                            "authenticationCertificates": [
                                {
                                    "id": "[parameters('sslCertData')]"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/backendHttpSettingsCollection"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "scalablehttpsettings",
                        "etag": "W/\"f5659c7c-d83a-431b-b456-097622a27c7b\"",
                        "properties": {
                            "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
                            "port": 7443,
                            "protocol": "Https",
                            "cookieBasedAffinity": "Enabled",
                            "connectionDraining": {
                                "enabled": false,
                                "drainTimeoutInSec": 60
                            },
                            "pickHostNameFromBackendAddress": false,
                            "path": null,
                            "requestTimeout": 300,
                            "authenticationCertificates": [
                                {
                                    "id": "[parameters('sslCertData')]"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/backendHttpSettingsCollection"
                    }
                ],
```

I am wondering how to give the certificate path to parameters('sslCertData') under authenticationCertificates. Can any one help me here please.

PS: The certificate is in .cer format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot do this directly. you need to convert certificate into base64 and pass it as base64 to the application gateway. also, i'm fairly sure you cant use `.cer` for listeners, only for auth (so end-to-end ssl). working example:

```
"sslCertificates": [ // these certificates can be used for listeners
    {
        "name": "offloadCertificate",
        "properties": {
            "data": "base64_value_of_.pfx",
            "password": "password_for_.pfx"
        }
    }
],
"authenticationCertificates": [ // these only for end-to-end ssl
    {
        "name": "authenticationCertificate",
        "properties": {
            "data": "base64_value_of_.cer"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: I converted it to base 64 and added it to authenticationCertificates. But when I execute the script it is throwing New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 23:24:26 - Resource Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways 'VVVgateway' failed with message '{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidRequestFormat",
    "message": "Cannot parse the request.",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "InvalidJsonReferenceFormat",
is not formatted correctly.
Could you please help on this

Comment: no way to help you without knowing what your template looks like, if its something like above you really need to strip all the extra properties, example: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-application-gateway-create/azuredeploy.json

Comment: The template is proper, It is throwing the error on authentication certificates: properties.backendHttpSettingsCollection[1].properties.authenticationCertificates.
I think the converted base64 is not formatted correctly. May be the certificate is the problem or the converted base64 key? Any idea?

Comment: Can some one help me on this??

Comment: I've told you how to do this

Comment: I am passing the converted base64 key value from .cer as a parameter in this "authenticationCertificates": [ // these only for end-to-end ssl
    {
        "name": "authenticationCertificate",
        "properties": {
            "data": "base64_value_of_.cer"
        }
    }
]
But I am getting an error saying, it is not formatted correctly. Could you help me on this?

Comment: whats the exact error text? how did you convert the certificate to base64? remove the comments from the template

Comment: I used the command base64 xxx.cer(Path of the certificate) from my command line. It gave me a key. Then I pasted this key in the string. Below is the error:
'{ "error": { "code": "InvalidRequestFormat", "message": "Cannot parse the request.", "details": [ { "code": "InvalidJsonReferenceFormat", Reference Id is not formatted correctly

Comment: has nothing to do with what you are asking, did you read the error text?

Comment: It is pointing and throwing an error where I am using the base64 key in the script. It says :
InvalidJsonReferenceFormat", Reference Id is not formatted correctly

Answer (score 0):

```
We have to use and declare as shown below. It works like a charm.

"httpscertificate": { 
        "defaultValue":"Base64 converted value"
    "type": "string"
        },

"authenticationCertificates": [
                    {
                        "properties": {
                            "data": "[parameters('httpscertificate')]"
                        },
                        "name": "Appgatewaybackendcert"
                    }
                ],

"backendHttpSettingsCollection": [
                    {
                        "name": "appGatewayBackendHttpSettings",
                        "properties": {
                            "Port": 80,
                            "Protocol": "Http",
                            "CookieBasedAffinity": "Disabled"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "nonscalablehttpssettings",
                        "etag": "W/\"f5659c7c-d83a-431b-b456-097622a27c7b\"",
                        "properties": {
                            "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
                            "port": 8443,
                            "protocol": "Https",
                            "cookieBasedAffinity": "Disabled",
                            "connectionDraining": {
                                "enabled": false,
                                "drainTimeoutInSec": 60
                            },
                            "pickHostNameFromBackendAddress": false,
                            "path": null,
                            "requestTimeout": 300,
                            "authenticationCertificates": [
                                {
                                    "Id": "[concat(variables('applicationGatewayID'), '/authenticationCertificates/checkpointsystems')]" //appGatewayBackendCert
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/backendHttpSettingsCollection"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "scalablehttpsettings",
                        "etag": "W/\"f5659c7c-d83a-431b-b456-097622a27c7b\"",
                        "properties": {
                            "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
                            "port": 7443,
                            "protocol": "Https",
                            "cookieBasedAffinity": "Disabled",
                            "connectionDraining": {
                                "enabled": false,
                                "drainTimeoutInSec": 60
                            },
                            "pickHostNameFromBackendAddress": false,
                            "path": null,
                            "requestTimeout": 300,
                            "authenticationCertificates": [
                                {
                                    "Id": "[concat(variables('applicationGatewayID'), '/authenticationCertificates/checkpointsystems')]"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/backendHttpSettingsCollection"
                    }
                ],
```